# How to add Payment/Bank transactions to an online store?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently using HTML, CSS, jQuery and some JavaScript to build/finish a website. And I'm now creating the store area but I have no clue of how to add the payment methods and everything that comes along with it.

Is there any kind free "pre-made" system I can download and include in my code? I also have no clue of what programming language is used for that, but I could read about it.

Answer (score 2):

Stripe and PayPal are two popular options for payment processing. Here is [an article](https://memberful.com/blog/stripe-vs-paypal/) that compares the two. Stripe's API works with Ruby, Python, PHP, Java, Node, and Go.

OpenACH and Omnipay (requires PHP) are open source payment processing systems that will require some more programming to have full functionality. OpenACH uses banks to process payments, which results in reduced costs. With Omnipay, you can choose from a number of different [payment gateways](http://omnipay.thephpleague.com/gateways/official/).

Answer (score 1):

There are several open-source e-commerce platforms. Two of the most popular are Magento and ZendCart but you can Google to find more. They're all essentially "content management systems" for stores and they let you add items to the store for display.

The second component is a cart. The items can, obviously, be added to this cart. The cart itself though is not functional without a payment processor of some kind that would be through a third-party service. You'll have to research them independently if you choose to go that route.

You will need both parts: the CMS / cart and the company that actually accepts the payments on your behalf and puts them in an account for you. This will require you to break up the HTML you currently have into a template. The structure of the template will vary based on the open-source cart you choose.

If all of this is a bit overwhelming, you also have the option of using PayPal "Buy Now" buttons. You only need to copy and paste the code from PayPal and add it to your HTML that way.

Comment: What about stores interested on selling their products on my site? What's the process? How does it work?

Comment: You might be able to find an eBay / auction clone if that's what you want. If it's an actual store, you'll need to either entire stuff manually or hire a team of developers to make something for you. There's only so much you can do yourself without learning software engineering.